# Change PHP to get image urls from mysql database instead of a .txt file

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, text-files

I'm very new to mysql (just started today) - I'm switching over from using .txt files. At the moment I am using a  PHP script which gets image links from a .txt file and loads them in a slideshow, according to which page you are on from the pagination.

I have managed to get the pagination working, which displays content from a database table. I'm just not sure how to go about adding images so that they change along with the pagination? How would I link multiple images with the content they go with (eg. dynamically made page 1 gets data from table row and has 5 images that load in a slideshow)? :S

current script using a .txt file:

```
<?php
    echo "<div id='portfolioslider'><div class='slider'>";
    $photos=file("work.txt");
    foreach($photos as $image){
        $item=explode("|",$image);
        if($item[0]==$fields[0]){
            $photo=trim($item[1]);
            echo"<div><img src='images/work/$photo' alt='' /></div>\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</div></div>"
?>
```

Comment: What library are you using to have PHP connect to mysql? mysql_* functions, mysqli, PDO, something else?

Comment: Umm I'm using phpmyadmin? ^^;

Comment: PHPMyAdmin has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this I would use three SQL tables (due to normalisation) we do this so that there is no data duplication within MySQL, the `photos` table has a many:1 relationship with `pages` (i.e. there are multiple photos to be associated with one page though we don't want to duplicate the photo ID within the pages table multiple times. Nor do we want to add multiple page ID's into the photos table. So we use a third table `location` to tie the two together and normalise the database.

```
table 1 (photos): 
    columns: photo_id(p-key), filename
    (maybe further fields such as description, alt, etc.)

table 2 (pages): 
    columns: page_id(p-key), page_info

table 3 (location): 
    columns: unique_key(p-key), page_id, photo_id
```

NOTE: Table 3 is the ONLY table that can have duplicated data i.e.

```
unique_key        page_id        photo_id
1                 1              1
2                 1              2
3                 1              3
4                 2              6
5                 2              7
6                 2              8
```

This way you keep the data in the two tables that actually containt the data totally free of any duplication, allowing you to add as many extra fields to each row that you would need.

Don't forget that the normalisation rules apply to every field. If you are inputing a new column into `photos` and realise that the new column could be applied to multiple photos it is time to start looking at a new table for that column and a normalisation table to keep duplications to a minimum.

There are very few exceptions to this rule, following it will make desiging SQL database applications in PHP alot simpler.

We can now use a series of SQL queries from within PHP to get the exact info you need per page. We know what page we are on so we will make sure that the page_id matches the page we are on, and grab all the asssociated photo_id's from `location`

```
$connect = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASS) or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query(
         "SELECT location.photo_id WHERE location.page_id=" . $page, $connect) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC) {
    $images[] = $row['photo_id'];
}
```

You can now use a foreach loop to cycle through the $images array and grab the photo urls

```
foreach ($images as $image) {

    $query = mysql_query(
             "SELECT filename FROM `photos` WHERE photo_id =" . $image, $connect) or die(mysql_error());

    $image_loc[] = mysql_fetch_row($query); // only one row should exist now!

}
```

You know have an numerical array $image_loc that contains all the image links associated with the page you are on.

There you go, quick crash course on database normalisation and how to set up your SQL tables! :)

Happy coding!
(I wrote the code all manually on here, please excuse any silly mistakes!)

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain that all to me! I think I kinda get it!! :D I will try and put this together later today! :) Just another n00b question, what would be the easiest way to duplicate the two tables and then merge them to create the third one, just so I don't have to type out all the data again? ^^;

Comment: No worries Jess, As you are using PHPMyAdmin to create / manage the tables you can duplicate them with that, and then remove / add columns as you please.

Comment: Hm I tried using the script, but I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected on line 10 - at the start of while ($row. Any ideas? ^^;

Comment: I see it, there is a missing ')' after the while statement. while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)`)`

Answer (score -1):

listen, you need to print all of your images and to put all of them in hidden besides the first 5.

after that you print the pagination links/ numbers (1,2,3...)
and each click will change to display status using jquery

Comment: Listen, you need to work out how to make a good answer. At the moment, this is of comment standard.